# SharePoint 2016: Sandboxed code execution request failed ((

Tags: sharepoint

I have faced with issue while trying to start workflow (ver 2010) with included SandBox solution.
The workflow process starting and then thrown with folowing exception:
Sandbox workflow error: Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionPipelineFailedException:

```
Sandboxed code execution request failed
. ---> System.Exception: System.InvalidOperationException    Server stack 
trace:     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.Verify.DoFailTag(UInt32 tag, ULSCat 
category, Type type, String format, Object[] args)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.ExecuteRequest(Type 
userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String 
affinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.Execute(Type 
userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String 
affinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)    
System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)    Exception rethrown
 at [0]:     
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPUserCodeExecutionHostProxy.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinityBucketName, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, SPUserCodeActivationSiteInfo activationSite, Boolean isRetry)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, SPUserCodeActivationSiteInfo activationSite, Boolean isRetry)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.SPUserCodeWorkflowActivity.ExecuteUserCode()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.SPUserCodeWorkflowActivity.System.Workflow.ComponentModel.IActivityEventListener<System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutionStatusChangedEventArgs>.OnEvent(Object sender, ActivityExecutionStatusChangedEventArgs e)    
 at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorDelegateInfo`1.ActivityExecutorDelegateOperation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime)    
 at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()
```

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service successfully started with no Compliant issues

In the "Services" windows console the "SharePoint user Code Host" servise runned ok. The account of this service have Full

access rights on the Web Application and have "sa" rights on the SQL Server.

This issue thrown my brain :( Please help.